# How to store cart data in local storage and in app the way if some one try to edit in local storage data it wont relfect in my UI

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I have built the shop app using vuejs with vuex state management, in which I have store cart data of unlogin users in a cart like product name, shop name, product price, etc.
but if I do changes in local storage it reflects on my UI also. I know anyone can edit in local storage but is there any way to store cart data, like if any changes made in local storage won't affect my UI data and after editing local storage and reloading the page I should get his cart as before the edit. I am using node.js in the backend.

Comment: why don't you just use vuex to store items in the cart.

Comment: on reload i wont get that data as states wont work on reload